# az cli how to set webapp runtime

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am aware that, from a Windows environment, I cannot set my webapp to `dotnetcore` runtime due to the following bug : https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/7688

However I'm trying to do it this way :

```
az resource create -g my-rg --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -n my-app --properties '{""siteConfig"": { ""metadata"": [{""CURRENT_STACK"": ""dotnetcore""}] }}'
```

There's no error message. But when I go to the azure portal, I see that the stack is not set to dotnetcore and remains on current value (dotnet). Is it the correct way to change the stack ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
az resource create -g my-rg --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -n my-app --properties "{\"siteConfig\": { \"metadata\": [{\"name\":\"CURRENT_STACK\",\"value\":\"dotnetcore\"}] }}"
```

I test it at my side, it can change the runtime:

[image]

Comment: yes, that works. In my case I also had to change the \" with double quotes ` --properties '{""siteConfig"": { ""metadata"": [{""name"":""CURRENT_STACK"",""value"":""dotnetcore""}] }}'`. Thank you !